# Is it possible to install rpm package from a Nexus yum repo using Maven?

Tags: maven, nexus, rpm

I would like to create a zip with some files and rpm packages using Maven assembly plugin and I would like to know if there is a way to download the rpm from a Nexus yum repository with the pom.xml (as a dependency or anything else).
I have found the rpm-maven-plugin but it can only create an rpm, it can't download it from Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, I used mvn wagon:

```
mvn wagon:upload-single -Dwagon.serverId=<ServerID> -Dwagon.url=http://<ServerUrl>/repository/<NexusReposirory>/<RPM file name> -Dwagon.fromFile=<RPM file>
```